# How to utilise Event aggregator in MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, prism, mef, prism-4

I am running the latest PRISM 4.2. Unfortunately the Event Aggregator tutorial in the documentation is driven via Unity instead of MEF. And I can't get it running under MEF.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        [Import]
        public IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run();
        }
    }
```

**Bootstrapper.cs**

```
public class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return new MainWindow();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();
            App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
            App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

            AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(this.GetType().Assembly));
        }

        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = new ModuleCatalog();

            return moduleCatalog;
        }

    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IView
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**MainViewModel.cs:**

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(MainViewModel))]
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase, IServiceCallback
    {
        [Import]
        public IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public MainViewModel()
        {            
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppExitEvent>().Publish("");

        }
     }
```

Despite the `[import]` the event aggregator is always null both in App.xaml.cs and in MainViewModel. Why is that?
The second question is do I have to export my Viewmodels as a module (as I did above) to use an even aggregator inside them?

**UPDATE:**

Proof that latest version of [PRISM](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/117297) doesn't support `ComposeExportedValue` anymore.

[image]

> 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer' does
>   not contain a definition for 'ComposeExportedValue' and no extension
>   method ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this would be what *SchubertJ* replied on your same question at **CodePlex**:

- [How to utilise Event aggregator in MEF?](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/533456)

As a deeper analyisis, the **Import** attribute on Properties would not be resolved until the constructor finishes. That is why you would need to inject the **EventAggregator** dependency through the constructor as a parameter if this dependency would be used on the constructor implementation.

Therefore, if you would like to use the ***EventAggregator*** dependency on the **ViewModel** constructor, you should use **[ImportConstructor]** attribute instead, and ask the container for the **EventAggregator** instance by retreiving it as a parameter:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
       this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

       this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish("");
    }
}
```

You may find more related information regarding both import alternatives in the following post:

- [MEF - [Import] vs [ImportingConstructor]](http://brendanforster.com/mef-import-vs-importingconstructor.html)

I hope this helped you, Regards.

Comment: Glad to hear that. However, do you have any suggesions for my answer that haven't made you upvote it? Highlights, poor issue explanation perhaps? Thank you.

Comment: Done. Accepted answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your bootstrapper class have this method :

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
     base.ConfigureContainer();
     Container.ComposeExportedValue(new EventAggregator());
}
```

You should look at this article as it is answer both your first and second question in better details.
http://www.gonetdotnet.info/posts/wpf-articles/wpf-module-communication

Update:

If you create a class as below it will match your  export with your import.

```
public class EventAggProvider
   {
     [Export(typeof(IEventAggregator))]
     public IEventAggregator eventAggregator { get { return new EventAggregator(); } }
   }
```

Comment: where is your article

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the `ConfigureAggregateCatalog` instead of `ConfigureContainer`? I thought the former handles the MEF consumable parts within the application.

Comment: your article has nothing to do with MEF and eventagregator

Comment: @K.B read the article, the author is using MEF, and the way he uses it answers both questions here.

Comment: @TYY, I just tried what you suggested, it says `ComposeExportedValue` not found. In the latest version these things seems to have changed. I worked on that article 3 hours ago. I couldn't get it working either. In StackOverflow answers should have a code suggestion instead of further articles. ;) Thanks

Comment: @Hooman I dont have the latest Prism, but I am also able to do this and it works. Look at my updated answer and see if that gets you going. I can't vouch that it is the correct route to follow though

Answer (score 1):

It is a little late, but there is also a solution for the case in which you want the EventAggregator gets injected in property. Implement '**IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification**' and use the eventaggregator in '**OnImportsSatisfied**' method.

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase,  IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [Import]
    public IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppExitEvent>().Publish("");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`EventAggregator` does not depend on `MEF or Unity` it's design pattern coined by Martin Fowler and it's based on publisher subscriber scenario

try  to follow this steps

//this should be in your infrastructure layer

```
public  static class EventAggregatorHelper
{
  private static IEventAggregator _Current = new EventAggregator();
  public static IEventAggregator Current
  {
    get
    {
      return _Current;
    }
  }
}



The HandleAppExitEvent is a class declared as shown below:

public class AppExitEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<String>
{
} 

and the subscriber would be something like this:
```

in your **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainViewModel();  
 //In this case the HandleAppExitEvent and the subscriber that deals with this event.                   
 EventAggregatorHelper.Current.GetEvent<AppExitEvent>().   Subscribe(HandleAppExitEvent);  

            }
      //note that this method should be public 

 public void HandleAppExitEvent(string mess)
    {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mess))
       {
          //Do whatever you need to do here.
       }
    }

    }
```